# Pushing code from Xcode to Visual Studio Team Service

Tags: azure-devops, xcode9

I am trying to push my source code to Visual Studio Team Services.
When i push my code i got the following error from Xcode.
The source control operation failed because the URL "https://test.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/myProj" cannot be used with Git.

Things which i tried:
1.Create Remote origin with Remote Name: Origin, Location: "https://test.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/myProj"
2.After commit i can't push my code

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following steps, to see whether you have missed anything:

1. Create a local Git repo for your Xcode project. Create a local Git repo for your existing projects not in version control by going to **Source Control**, **Create Working Copy**... . Select the projects to add to the local Git repo and select **Create**. Xcode creates a Git repo for your code and adds a commit with your project files.

[image]

2. Create a new Git repo in VSTS for your Xcode project. It seems you have created one `https://test.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/myProj`.
3. Push your project.

[image]

You can refer to the link below for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/share-your-code-in-git-xcode?view=vsts