# Configure option in source control missing from xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, git, tfs, azure-devops

I am writing an iOS app from scratch in xCode 10.

I want to use TFS (Azure DevOps) for code push.

I am following these articles:

[Share your code in Git using Xcode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-xcode?view=vsts)

[Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50265904/pushing-code-from-xcode-to-visual-studio-team-service)

This solution is meant for xCode 9 but, xCode 10 doesn't have any options like this.
[Configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXkoK.png)

How to do this thing in xCode 10?

Answer (score 0):

The configure menu itself is simply about defining remotes.
You can fall back to the command line for that:

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git remote add origin https://yourProject.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/yourProject
```

But you still need the Git menus in XCode 10 for the integration to work properly.

Try and create a new project (for testing) in XCode10, [selecting Git as source control](http://Create%20a%20local%20Git%20repo%20when%20you%20create%20a%20new%20project.%20Choose%20Create%20Git%20repository%20on%20My%20Mac%20when%20creating%20a%20new%20project.):

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/_img/share-your-code-in-git-xcode/xcodenewproject.png?view=vsts]

Comment: Thank you.
Regarding "selecting Git as source control" Again! no such option in xCode 10.

Comment: @SheikhAtif Did you try and upgrade, then reset xcode-select, as in https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/338541?

Comment: @SheikhAtif Or install the xcode command-line through Apple Store? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/338541

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: @SheikhAtif I mean: maybe the lack of Git is linked to the XCode 'commandLineTool', hence my two link to try and upgrade that.